# Unnest array on bigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

My BigQuery table has some regular columns plus one array of structs.

I'd like to run a query to flatten this structure, having one row for each element of the array, and duplicated values for the other columns.

I tried `UNNEST` but the result is not what I need:

```
SELECT
  col_a, col_b, array
FROM
  `table`,
UNNEST(array)
```

This query shows the value for `col_a` and `col_b` only once, and are null for the remaining rows of the array.

How can I change the query so that `col_a` and `col_b` are repeated for each row?

Answer (score 1):

Use below

```
SELECT
  col_a, col_b, el
FROM
  `table`,
UNNEST(array) as el
```